# What happens when you give NULL to a PHP function that expects string?

Tags: php

For example to: `preg_match` or when you use concatenation?

Answer to comments:

I can test for `preg_match` or concatenation results, yes.

But there is a difference between:

PHP function with the signature: `int f(string $parameter)`

- Will PHP convert the NULL to empty string **before** the `f` function gets it, or
- Will the `f` function get NULL even if signature expects string, so the function may throw exceptions or behave not as it would received an empty string.

(I can't test this, because I can't write `string` type for a parameter at function signature.)

Comment: try it out. It will just cast it into a empty string

Comment: Wouldn't a two second test on your own machine be much faster than writing the question here and waiting for an answer?

Comment: Some questions need not to be asked but done.

Comment: It still depends on the specific function implementation. There is no general typecasting, or type diregarding, notices or exceptions. It wholly depends on the userland or C implementation. -- Don't make your question this broad or abstract if you have an actual inquiry.

Comment: Thank you mario! Maybe I was not clear with my question. Sorry for that! Just wanted to know, that will NULL type casted to empty string before the PHP function gets it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the function you used for. Some may support null as parameter, some not. Some may throw notice, but dont forget that null may be converted to "" (empty string)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wanted to know what can I expect in many cases - and can I expect a notice.